# Using raise function to stop execution of further code in python after an error

Tags: python, python-2.7, raise

I use `raise` function in python 2.7 as a way to stop further code being executed, without exiting, when a condition is not met. This is shown in example below:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

def foo():
    a = 3
    if a == 2:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('Hello', 'Yup yup yup')
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('Hello', 'My bad!')
        raise

    tkMessageBox.showinfo('Further code' ,"You shouldn't see me if a is not 2")

app = Tk()
app.title("ABC")
app.geometry()


filetype_fasta = [('fasta files', '*.fasta'), ('All files', '*.*')]
button_templ = Button(app, text = 'Click me', width =6, command = foo)
button_templ.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

app.mainloop()
```

It works fine for a complicated script I have. My question is this - Is there any potential problem, that I should be aware of, in using `raise` this way? If yes, is there a better/common method to do the same thing?

Edit: Example changed to demonstrate the idea better.

Comment: why not use sys.exit()?

Comment: @chris, I should have mentioned that this program will be GUI based and hence I don't want gui to exit everytime it runs into error. I will change the example to explain better. Thanks!

Comment: if thats being called within a method, how about using return? that will stop further code executing

Comment: there's absolutely nothing wrong with using raise

Comment: Unless there isn't an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest problem that would raise with the 'raise' statement is the lack of communication. When you use raise, you better add a doc string for the function in which raise is used(that is, for what conditions the function/method would throw an error, what are the errors/cause and so on).

Also be aware that the calling function(the function that calls the method `foo` in your example) needs to have an except properly to handle the raise. Even a few coders actually use raise statement to prevent multiple return statements throughout the code. However, the raise will be handled in the same method/function in those cases.

To put things in a better perspective(for the sake of a new programmer or the programmer who just moved to your project), you can create custom exceptions and raise them at appropriate places rather than just giving a raise statement. As Joran Beasley mentioned in the comments, there's absolutely nothing wrong with using raise. Except that there should be a purpose more than just break the flow with using raise statement.

To be precise, there won't be any problem as such with using a raise statement. However, if you are going to use raise statement, do follow a few courtesies that makes the life of the one maintaining the code simpler.